# Addressable asset build failure

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity-webgl

[Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7Ynf.png)

I am building a webgl based games. This games was in android build. I have converted it into webgl. When I am trying to build the game in webgl these errors appear. I couldn't find enough resources for solving these issues. If anyone encounter this issues in their project please help me to solve this..

I am searching for resources to solve these issues.

Comment: You need to look at the details saying why it failed.